# How to get all mails with flagged use php

Tags: php, imap

I am setting up a webmail.
There is a fold like 'flagged' meaning that the mail with flagged.
However ,these mails mybe in SENT folder or in INBOX folder or in DRAFT folder.
Is there anyway to get them quickly?Because the  imap_open function only use one folder each time.
just like

```
imap_open("{localhost:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}SENT", "username", "password")
imap_open("{localhost:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}DRAFT", "username", "password")
imap_open("{localhost:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "username", "password")
```

if not , I need to user a loop,then merge three part of them together!
I also use paging !Oh, That's so crazy! Who can help me!

Comment: That's how IMAP works. Read folder one by one...

Comment: It is so bad,Maybe! Thanks a lot!